# Sequence of time with lubridate for special months

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I want to generate a sequence of time with lubridate, lets say from 1995 to 2005, but only for the summer months from May to September.

I have this already, but how can I choose only the summer months?

```
seq(ymd('1995-05-01'),ymd('2005-09-30'),by='day')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the month and then filter:

```
library(lubridate)
day_list <- seq(ymd('1995-05-01'),ymd('2005-09-30'),by='day')
day_list <- day_list[which(month(day_list) %in% c(5:9))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was what I was looking for!

Comment: @Mr.Spock Please accept the answer if it addresses your need.